# Boot a Mac in Target Mode with Different OS

Tags: linux, macos, mac, firewire

I have two PowerPC macs, one running OSX, and one running Linux. I would like to boot the one running Linux into target mode so that the OSX mac can access it via firewire.

Is this possible? Or does the OS have to be OSX for target mode to work?